# Is Adderall safe for someone who donated a kidney?

Tags: adhd, kidney, add-adhd, stimulants, organ-donation

I donated my kidney many years ago to some random two year old.  It was major surgery, but it did get me a month paid vacation on short term disability and was a great way to lose weight (stupid kidneys weight me down) so hey I figured it was worth it ;).

I've also been taking Adderall for ADHD, and currently am on Adderall XR.  My doctor just prescribed test to check on my kidney functionality, regular procedure for Adderall.  However, it reminded me that Adderall can affect a kidney which I thought may be a problem since I only have the one remaining.

My doctor doesn't seem to consider this an issue, and I'm inclined to trust her on this.  However, I'm also not overly committed to Adderall, I can easily take any other stimulant medication (though, I wouldn't be surprised if most of them have the same kidney risks?) or Straterra if they are safer.  Is there a risk, even a small one, sufficient to warrant at least considering an alternate medication if I have only one Kidney?  or is my doctor right in considering the risk low enough to not warrant worrying about changing to another stimulant if I have one that seems to work?

Comment: You're not just asking us for personal medical advice here, you're also asking us to judge your doctor's opinions. We can't provide either. There's a legitimate question here but uncovering it means deleting about 90% of what you wrote and boiling it down to 1 or 2 sentences that don't have much to do with you and your case. Could you do that, please?